can't load custom library on Codeigniter 3 on production server
I've look to all existing question about this issue but still couldn't find the answer. I'm working on CentOS 7 Server.
Here is my custom library that I put in application/libraries
Simas_Bridge.php
class Simas_Bridge
{
  private $CI;
  private $client;
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->CI = &get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->helper(['file']);
    $this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
  }
  public function get_dokumen_drh($nip = null)
  {
     ///.... Some Code
  }
}

and I call the library from my Controller like this
Form.php
class Form extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('simas_bridge');
    }

    public function uploadFile(){
        $this->simas_bridge->get_dokumen_drh('xxxxxxx'); >>>> The Error happens here!!!
    }
}

I've tried to change the way I call the library to $this->load->library('Simas_Bridge') and call the method with $this->Simas_Bridge->get_dokumen_drh().
Try to change the permission to 750 for Simas_Bridge.php file on the server. It still doesn't work.
Always get these error
Unable to load the requested class: Simas_Bridge
What could be wrong?

Did you try checking the docs?
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html#naming-conventions - specifically "Class names and file names must match."

@Don'tPanic, i have tried it with SimasBridge, still got the same error

How did you try loading it when you corrected the name?  Did you also try using the convention shown in the docs, without capital 'B'?  And when you did that, how did you try loading it?  There are only a few conventions, if you really have followed them all (at the same time) and it isn't working, you have another problem caused by something you haven't shown us.

Here is my custom library that I put in application/libraries SimasBridge.php SimasBridge !=Simas_Bridge

@Vickel i'm sorry i have typo on that, firstly i try with Simas_Bridge and not working, after that i try with SimasBridge and it's not working either, gonna try Simasbridge rn

Try to follow naming convention suggested by Codeigniter, in their documentation they suggesting this:

File names must be capitalized. For example: Myclass.php
Class declarations must be capitalized. For example: class Myclass
Class names and file names must match.

So based on that what you should do is

rename your file from Simas_Bridge.php to Simasbridge.php
Class declaration change to Class Simasbridge
then call the class by using $this->load->library('simasbridge');

for more details please refer to this link Codeigniter 3 official documentation

Already tried this approach, still coudln't work. And got the same error too.

thats weird, try to change ownership Simasbridge file and then test again.

what should i change the ownership? for now it's :apache, with 750 permission

I don't know what's wrong, but i retry it from start, and this works

can I know what you doing? so if other user find same problem they can read from this post? :)

just like waht u recommend, i rename the file back to Simas_Bridge.php first, and the class to Simas_Bridge, and call it as simas_bridge , and then i redo what u tell me as the documentation says, i rename the file to Simasbridge.php, rename the class to Simasbridge, and call it on my controller construct with $this->load->library('simasbridge')

okay, glad to hear that :)
